# Seeing all the changes when editing a commit

Tags: git

My lead tech asked me today to remove all the tests from my branch. I have 4 commits, each one contains tests. I don't want to make an extra commit that removes all tests from them because it would look messy in my opinion.

Instead, I'd like to edit the existing commits. I can do `git commit --interactive` and mark the commits with `edit` but I wouldn't be able to selectively pick the chunks I want to discard. For that, I tried `git reset --soft HEAD~` and keep only the changes I want (eg, being able to use `git reset`). However, when I do that and then `git rebase --continue`, git tells me that I have unstaged changes, even though I don't.

Is there a way to get all the changes back in the index when editing a git commit in the history?

EDIT:

> @jonrsharpe
>   Isn't having an extra commit that says why the tests were removed a better record of what actually happened?

Yes probably, but even if that is what I decide in the end, I'd rather use git tools to remove the tests than editing the files manually. That would require to see the changes from the 4 commits in my index.

Comment: Isn't having an extra commit that says why the tests were removed a better record of what actually happened? But you can do it with `git reset HEAD^` per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) (see the splitting example).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I guess that works. I edited my question.

Comment: *"I'd rather use git tools"* - why?!

Comment: Because I do everything with magit and it's much faster than editing the files manually. I also do less mistakes with git because I work on diffs, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a weird request from your lead tech, but without getting into *that* discussion, this should actually be quite easy if your commits just add tests and later commits don't make changes to them.

Your strategy of doing an interactive rebase to edit the commits sounds good.

The process of editing a commit would be something like:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git add -i <files>  # assuming your test code is in files that have other changes
git commit
git reset --hard
```

I suspect you're missing the hard reset at the end.

After doing a soft reset, you're at the previous commit, but with all the changes from the commit you were editing. Interactively adding the files will allow you to commit something that doesn't correspond exactly to the files in your working copy. After committing that, you're still in a state where the changes from the original commit that you chose not to commit are in your working copy, and you need to get rid of these to let git continue with the rebase.

Doing a hard reset will change your *working copy* to match the commit you're resetting to, throwing away any local changes; in this case making your working copy match what you just committed.

If your tests are in separate files, then the edit step is easier, it would just be:

```
git rm <test files>
git commit --amend
```

Then continue with your rebase.

Comment: Thansk for the answer. Can you explain why I need to `reset --hard` at the end?

Comment: @qleguennec That's what the paragraph after "I suspect you're missing the hard reset at the end." is trying to do :) I'll try and make it more explicit.